# Why doesn't bash interpret the asterisk character when used with xargs command?

Tags: bash, wildcards

As far as I understand, the asterisk character `*` has a special meaning in Bash and in order to print the literal character we need to either escape it (`\*`) or quote it (`"*"` or `'*'`.

However, when I have tried the following:

```
$ seq 3 |  xargs -I *  echo *
1
2
3
```

Why doesn't Bash interpret `*` in the example above?
But in the  following example it did interpret it as a wildcard character (it matches the file in the current directory):

```
$ seq 3 |  xargs -I*  echo * # no space between -I and *
main.py
main.py
main.py
```

Could you please explain the logic behind this?

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bash *did* expand the star in your first example.

Assuming that the current directory contains only one file, `main.py`,
here is what happened:

```bsh
$ seq 3 | xargs -I *  echo *
# Expands to:
$ seq 3 | xargs -I main.py echo main.py
```

This asks to do `echo main.py` on each input, replacing `main.py` with
that input (because of `-I main.py`). And this is what you observed:
the three templates turn from `echo main.py` to `echo 1`, `echo 2`,
`echo 3`.

In the second case, the star being just next to `-I` prevented that
word from expanding (since no files match the pattern `-I*`):

```bsh
$ seq 3 | xargs -I*  echo *
# Expands to:
$ seq 3 | xargs -I* echo main.py
```

This asks xargs to replace instances of `*` (a literal star) in the
template `echo main.py` with the input. Since the template does not
include the placeholder `*` at all, it prints `main.py` each time.

(With `failglob` enabled in Bash, or in zsh with the default settings, the glob matching nothing would produce an error and the command would not run.)

If your command had protected both occurrences of `*`, then you would
have obtained the same output as in your first attempt:

```bsh
$ seq 3 | xargs -I '*' echo '*'
1
2
3
```

---

If you happened to have more than one file in the directory, then the unquoted `*` might create problems more visibly. E.g. if there the two files `main.py` and `other.py`, then:

```bsh
$ seq 3 | xargs -I *  echo *
# Expands to:
$ seq 3 | xargs -I main.py other.py echo main.py other.py
```

and `xargs` will try to run `other.py echo main.py other.py` as the command (with `main.py` replaced by the current input string). That will likely give a "command not found" error from `xargs`. Or, if the second filename in sort order would match a runnable program in `PATH`, then `xargs` would run *that program*, and not `echo`.

---

A useful trick to get some amount of visibility into which Bash
expansions happen is to run `set -o xtrace`. With the flag set,
you can see the expansions on lines starting with `+`:

```
$ set -o xtrace
$ seq 3 | xargs -I * echo *
+ seq 3
+ xargs -I main.py echo main.py
1
2
3

$ seq 3 | xargs -I* echo *
+ seq 3
+ xargs '-I*' echo main.py
main.py
main.py
main.py

$ seq 3 | xargs -I '*' echo '*'
+ seq 3
+ xargs -I '*' echo '*'
1
2
3
```

Comment: You may also ask `xargs` to show the commands it's executing, using its `-t` option.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes, but in this case it will not tell what's going on. Instead `set -x` will show that.

Comment: [`set` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)